# Libgdx: Gradle import eclipse only showing root folder instead of projects

Tags: eclipse, import, gradle, libgdx

When I try to import my libgdx project into eclipse as a Gradle import, instead of showing all 5 (-core, -desktop, -android, -ios, -html) it finds only the root folder in which all those 5 are in.

I've not freshly created this project, I've worked on it a long time and only now get how to use Gradle.

Anyone have any suggestions on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who viewed!

It was a very weird error. It resolved after I cut the project out of my workspace, repeated the process (then it worked). I put it back into my workspace to see if it would work and in fact it did.